# ¿Como convertir json a objeto en c#?

Tags: c#, json

Tengo el siguiente json.

```
{Estudiante:
      {nombre:'paco',
       edad: 20,
       sexo: 'm'},
 Recibos:
       [{folio:'A1213',
         fecha:'10-02-2017',
         total: 56},
         {folio:'A1213',
         fecha:'10-02-2017',
         total: 56}]
 }
```

Para convertir estudiante utilizo lo siguiente:

```
       JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
       JToken objeto = jObject["Estudiante"];
       string nombre = (string) objeto["nombre"];
```

Pero no se como realizar ese proceso con Recibos.
  Gracias.

Comment: "Recibos" es un array dentro del objeto "Estudiante"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria lo mismo solo que como es array se utiliza `JArray` en vez de `JObject` y lo lees utilizando un `foreach`:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken objeto = jObject["Estudiante"];
string nombre = (string) objeto["nombre"];      

JArray recibos = (JArray)jObject["Recibos"];    

foreach(JObject item : recibos)
{
    string folio = item.GetValue("filio").ToString();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Lo intente pero me manda el siguiente error en el foreach para recibos: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication3.exe

Comment: Recuerda que tienes que validar que en tu json la propiedad folio ,por ejemplo, exista o tenga valor, de lo contrario te lanzara el error.

Comment: Olvídalo tenia una variable mal escrita, funciona perfecto muchas gracias!!

Comment: Aunque solo me toma el valor del segundo recibo.

Comment: Muy probable porque estas acediendo solo al segundo recibo.